# Is there a way to get processor details without using information from bios?

Tags: linux, cpu, timing

With Linux, is there a way to retrieve the processor model without taking information from bios? I don't know which processor is really mounted. I want to set up the right processor timing, but I don't know the processor type. Every time I change the timing for the processor in BIOS another processor type is determined (I should be an Athlon XP +1500, I think, but I don't know really).

I think with

```
less /proc/cpuinfo
```

the results depends on the timing that is set in bios.

So could you tell me how I can find out which processor is really mounted?

Comment: What indicator do you have that the processor type is changing?

Comment: My bios shows the processor type depending on the clock settings and the resulting frequency. If I set the base-timing to 100 MHz the resulting cpu-speed is 1 GHz and the BIOS show "AMD Athlon XP". If I set the base-timing to 133 MHz the resulting frequency ist 1,333GHz the BIOS shows "AMD Athlon XP 1500+". Now I am a bit confused which processor is really mounted.

Comment: Does `less /proc/cpuinfo` also show different results?

Comment: yes it does show the same names like the bios shows

Comment: Ok, what do you get if you run `sudo dmidecode -t processor`? Does it change for each setting, or stay the same?

Comment: at a first glance it looks good, i will test it tomorrow thanks

Comment: According to wikipedia, AMD didn't release the Athlon XP at "less than" the 1500+ performance rating...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon#Athlon_XP.2FMP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Athlon_XP_microprocessors#Athlon_XP_.22Palomino.22_.28Model_6.2C_180_nm.29... so it's probably a situation with the BIOS to "best guess" based on clock rate. Try matching the cpu signature from dmidecode to the AMD model numbers. That should be the correct CPU version.

Answer (score 2):

There is some information in `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu`.

Most of the files in there behave like text file and can be viewed with e.g. `cat`. They also be fairly easy to parse automatically.

Comment: I know these locations, but I think their contents base on the information gathered from BIOS

Comment: No, the kernel probes those informations directly from the hardware at startup time. Additional details can sometimes be found in the first lines of dmesg output.